# NTFS symbolic links in a multi-OS environment

Tags: linux, windows, multi-boot, ntfs, symbolic-link

On a system with GNU/Linux / Windows dualboot, I want to save disk space by sharing a partition with data. It is supposedly not a problem to use a cross-platform NTFS partition by assigning it a letter in Windows (e.g. `D:\`) and mounting it somewhere on GNU/Linux (e.g. `/data`). I wonder, however, if NTFS symbolic relative links would function correctly in such a setup.

To illustrate the potential problem, consider a directory `MyDir` in parent directory `MyParent` which is in the root directory of the partition. On Windows, I create a symbolic link named `MyLink` in the root directory of the partition that links to `MyDir`:

```
Partition structure:
<root>
- MyLink => "MyParent\MyDir"
- MyParent
  - MyDir
```

Since `MyDir` is represented as `D:\MyParent\MyDir\` on Windows, the symbolic link works fine. However, on GNU/Linux, the path would be different, e.g. `/data/MyParent/MyDir/` (note the different path separator `/`). Would the symlink function correctly?

---

As for the context, I'd like to symlink `C:\Users\<username>\` to the shared partition on Windows and set the GNU/Linux's user home directory to the same place so only system-dependent files are kept apart; I would also like to make symlinks inside the partition for convenience (e.g. `/data/<username>/.minecraft/` to `/data/<username>/AppData/Roaming/.minecraft/` to reuse Minecraft installation).

Thank you.

Comment: "Would the symlink function correctly?" – What keeps you from just trying? You can write your own answer afterwards.

Comment: Firstly, I'd like to know it in advance not to end up in a situation where I need to reinstall everything. Secondly, the symlinks may work some of the time but not reliably; I may only learn that they _don't_ function correctly when it is crucial. I decided to post a question here because I inevitably need to wait before I could try to do it myself, and also because someone may have a good enough idea about NTFS to answer based not on experience but on knowledge (which I think is better). Of course, if I test it before the question get answered, I'll answer it myself.

Answer (score 2):

After trying for myself, it turns out the symlinks do work just fine; no tuning required.

Comment: What about the difference in paths e.g. `/data/MyParent/MyDir/` - how is this solved?

Comment: I am afraid I did not understand your question, @AngelosPikoulas